Metadata-Generation Failed Error when insalling Xdot
I'm running into an issue while trying to install xdot using pip with the following output:
 Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      + meson setup #####\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1mh_6ku6\pygobject_894d8c8e7c5f41c08d5b26e56dffd291 C:#####\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1mh_6ku6\pygobject_894d8c8e7c5f41c08d5b26e56dffd291\.mesonpy-4qw_h8dh -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md -Dtests=false -Dwheel=true --wrap-mode=nofallback --native-file=C:######\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1mh_6ku6\pygobject_894d8c8e7c5f41c08d5b26e56dffd291\.mesonpy-4qw_h8dh\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.4.1
      Source dir: C:####\Local\Temp\pip-install-1mh_6ku6\pygobject_894d8c8e7c5f41c08d5b26e56dffd291
      Build dir: C:####\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1mh_6ku6\pygobject_894d8c8e7c5f41c08d5b26e56dffd291\.mesonpy-4qw_h8dh
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pygobject
      Project version: 3.48.2
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 14.1.0 "cc (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.42
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python3 found: YES (C:\Python311\python.exe)
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.11
      Found pkg-config: YES (C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\pkg-config.EXE) 2.2.0
      WARNING: Found CMake 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\cmake.EXE' but couldn't run it
      Found CMake: NO
      Run-time dependency gobject-introspection-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
      Not looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gobject-introspection-1.0 because:
      Use of fallback dependencies is disabled.

      ..\meson.build:29:9: ERROR: Dependency 'gobject-introspection-1.0' is required but not found.

      A full log can be found at ####\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1mh_6ku6\pygobject_894d8c8e7c5f41c08d5b26e56dffd291\.mesonpy-4qw_h8dh\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I have installed cmake, updated pip, updated my Python installation, and downloaded gobject-introspection using MSYS2, and am still recieving the same metadata-generation-failed error. My machine is running Windows 10, Python version is 3.12.4, and pip version is 24.0, for reference. Any idea on what is causing the issue and what I can do to fix it?
